# ASP.NET MVC 4 Incorrect Home Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

after I had added the **Product** route in my RouteConfig, my default homepage changed to Product page. How can I setup my home controller as my default homepage again.

```
     routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Product",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Products",
            url: "products/{categoryName}/{Id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", categoryName = "", Id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
```

Comment: Try out Phil Haack's route testing tool. [This article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) describes it and here is the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/).

Answer (score 0):

This is my route table. It doesn't use the route I marked on the table by default.

[Screenshot of the route table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEoFP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first and last will act the same way.The program will pick the first route it matches so you should hard code the first route like this.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Product",
        url: "Product/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" }
    );
```

or you should remove the first route. i think that you should go with this approach.

```
      routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Products",
            url: "products/{categoryName}/{Id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", categoryName = "", Id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

**Explanation:** 
from a stephen walter's [post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

The default route table contains a single route (named Default). The Default route maps the first segment of a URL to a controller name, the second segment of a URL to a controller action, and the third segment to a parameter named id.

Imagine that you enter the following URL into your web browser's address bar:

```
/Home/Index/3
```

The Default route maps this URL to the following parameters:

```
  controller = Home

    action = Index

    id = 3
```

When you request the URL /Home/Index/3, the following code is executed:

```
HomeController.Index(3)
```

The Default route includes defaults for all three parameters. If you don't supply a controller, then the controller parameter defaults to the value Home. If you don't supply an action, the action parameter defaults to the value Index. Finally, if you don't supply an id, the id parameter defaults to an empty string.

Let's look at a few examples of how the Default route maps URLs to controller actions. Imagine that you enter the following URL into your browser address bar:

```
/Home
```

Because of the Default route parameter defaults, entering this URL will cause the Index() method of the HomeController class in Listing 2 to be called.

Listing 2 - HomeController.cs

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

}

In Listing 2, the HomeController class includes a method named Index() that accepts a single parameter named Id. The URL /Home causes the Index() method to be called with an empty string as the value of the Id parameter.

Because of the way that the MVC framework invokes controller actions, the URL /Home also matches the Index() method of the HomeController class in Listing 3.

Listing 3 - HomeController.cs (Index action with no parameter)

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The Index() method in Listing 3 does not accept any parameters. The URL /Home will cause this Index() method to be called. The URL /Home/Index/3 also invokes this method (the Id is ignored).

The URL /Home also matches the Index() method of the HomeController class in Listing 4.

Listing 4 - HomeController.cs (Index action with nullable parameter)

```
 using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
    {
        [HandleError]
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index(int? id)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

In Listing 4, the Index() method has one Integer parameter. Because the parameter is a nullable parameter (can have the value Null), the Index() can be called without raising an error.

Finally, invoking the Index() method in Listing 5 with the URL /Home causes an exception since the Id parameter is not a nullable parameter. If you attempt to invoke the Index() method then you get the error displayed in Figure 1.

Listing 5 - HomeController.cs (Index action with Id parameter)

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```